# Missing files for SDL_Mixer

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2, sdl-mixer

I planned on adding sound effects to a smal project.
i downloaded the SDL_Mixer dev-library for mingw32,
moved all the files from its lib folder to the mingw32 lib folder, did the same for include and bin.
But iam still not able to compile anything using #include SDL2/SDL_mixer.h.

```
´C:/Development/SDL Mixer/include/SDL2/SDL_mixer.h:25:10: fatal error: SDL_stdinc.h: No such file or directory´
```

Maybe it is my makefile.

```
´build:
    gcc -Wfatal-errors \
    -std=c99 \
    ./*.c \
    -I"C:\Development\SDL2 MinGW 64\include" \
    -L"C:\Development\SDL2 MinGW 64\lib" \
    -I"C:\Development\SDL Mixer\include" \
    -L"C:\Development\SDL Mixer\lib" \
    -lmingw32 \
    -lSDL2main \
    -lSDL2 \
    -o example.exe´
```

i dont know why files are missing.

Comment: From where did you download SDL_mixer? Are you sure it's SDL**2**_mixer and not the one for SDL 1.2?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat i used this [link](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/) and the dev library

Comment: Do you have `SDL_stdinc.h` in `C:\Development\SDL2 MinGW 64\include`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ok i did that, that one error doesnt pop up anymore, now it has a lot of undefined appdata temp folder

Comment: Please post the exact errors.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat
i cant realy sleep without fixing this
errors: 
C:\Users\paulr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTHou4i.o:main.c:(.text+0x25e): Warnung: undefinierter Verweis auf ╗Mix_OpenAudio½
C:\Users\paulr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTHou4i.o:main.c:(.text+0x26a): Warnung: undefinierter Verweis auf ╗Mix_LoadMUS½
C:\Users\paulr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTHou4i.o:main.c:(.text+0xc23): Warnung: undefinierter Verweis auf ╗Mix_PlayMusic½
C:\Users\paulr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTHou4i.o:main.c:(.text+0xc6f): Warnung: undefinierter Verweis auf ╗Mix_FreeMusic½


basicly reads "undefined reference to"

Comment: Add `-lSDL2_mixer` (or something like that) at the end of the command.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat in the command line, or in my makefile?

Comment: In the makefile, right after `-lSDL2`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you so much, it worked, i was able to play the file i wanted in my programm.